# What causes "ghost" classes to appear in Tomcat/Eclipse after big changes?

Tags: eclipse

I recently renamed one of the projects in my workspace. As a result Hibernate is throwing errors on a "ghost" class which no longer exists and is not referenced anywhere in my entire workspace including, source files, hidden files, config files, derived files, and binary files.

See screenshot below for visual people.

[image]

**Where is the non-existing class name coming from? It is clearly being found by a component-scan.**

Every time this happens, I am able to work-around the issue by doing all the following:

1. Delete the Tomcat server
2. Delete all my projects from Eclipse
3. Re-clone projects from git into Eclipse
4. Re-create new Tomcat server and re-add the projects into them

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never mentioned whether you did a "Project->Clean..." from the menu.  That could very well help.  It's also not clear whether this is a Maven project.  If it is, then doing Maven->UpdateProject from the project context menu could help.

Comment: Yes, those were tried before resorting to the nuclear option of deleting the project.